# Display array line by line on spinner

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I have put content from a column in a spinner. It is a column from which i saved content using an array of checkbox's (Sparseboolean array) so meaning it has many words seperated with a ",". I managed to display the content in the spinner but it all coming in one line instead of each word coming on its own line and with the comma. here is the code i used to display the cursor spinner

```html
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllRows();

        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            String[] from = new String[]{"Facilities"};
            // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
            int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
            SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    cursor, from, to);
            mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spFacilityType.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }


        spFacilityType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view,
                                       int pos, long log) {


                Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Facilities"));

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

---

Viktor. Here is the code for getAllRows()

```html
public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
                where, null, null, null, KEY_STATION_NAME, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

---

Kyus Addiction. This is what i have tried. But the app is crashing

```html
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllRows();

        TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter simpleStringSplitter=new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(',');

        List<String> lables = (List<String>) dbHelper.getAllRows();

        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            String[] from = new String[]{"Facilities"};
            // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
            int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<>(AddReview.this, // This is your context
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, // This is your layout
                            lables); // This is your data

            spFacilityType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    position = index;
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Add code of  dbHelper.getAllRows();

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you stored the data like:

```
id  spinner_data    comment
--  ------------    -------
0   A1,A2,A3        my 'A' data
1   B2,B4,B6        my 'B' data
2   C3,C6,C9        my 'C' data
```

So when you load and iterate over the cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllRows();
```

It's giving you exactly what you asked for...a single row:

```
0   A1,A2,A3        my 'A' data
```

And your spinner is showing the text as "A1,A2,A3"

If you want your existing code to work, you'd have to store each string as separate record:

```
id  spinner_data    comment
--  ------------    -------
0   A1              my 'A1' data
1   A2              my 'A2' data
2   A3              my 'A3' data
```

Alternatively, a (relatively) simple fix would be to switch to an ArrayAdapter.
What you could do is get the column data as a string

```
String data = cursor.getString(COLUMN_SPINNER_DATA); // A1,A2,A3
```

Parse that string (data) into a list of strings using some string tokenizer, I prefer guava's Splitter:

```
// Split using the comma (,) as a separator
Splitter spl = Splitter.onPattern(",");     
List<String> lstData = spl.split(data);
```

And now, instead of the SimpleCursorAdapter, instantiate an ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(SomeActivity.this, // This is your context
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, // This is your layout
                    lstData); // This is your data
```